# handle multiple tabs or refresh with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an application that implements a socket.io

I'm supporting multiple tabs/user/pages updates but the issue i that the array of sessions that hold the socket is increased in each refresh or a new tab.

I tried as I wrote below to remove socket with the same id, but each refresh or each new tab is a new socket (even if they have the same query)

my array is like:

```
 sessionId : {
    client_id
    ....
    sockets: [..list of sockets]

 }
```

while I sending events to the client i do smth like:

```
   sessions.forEach((data, clientId) => {
      data.sockets.forEach(socket => {
             send events here
      });
    });
```

in the client every time there is a connection I do the foolowing

```
    const { token, sessionId } = from Localstroage;

    const options = {
      query: {
        token,
        clientId: sessionId,
      },
      forceNew: true
    };

    this.server = io('/', { ...options, path: `${this.url}/socket.io` });
```

//adding new socket code:

```
  if (this.sessions.hasClientId(id) {
      this.sessions[id].sockets.push(socket);
    } else {
      this._sessions.set(
        id,
        new Session(clientId, [socket])
      );
    }
```

so now I will have a list of the socket in a specific session but that socket will be with the same client Id

**on refresh for example the socket will create a new connection with the same client id **

My solution was to no push a socket to the list if the socket in the inner array already has the client id

but this does not work with tabs because probably each tab, each refresh is a new session

this behavior is ok for tabs but does not ok when you refresh the page or close tabs

update::

local storage obj:

```
 {
   token: "xxx",
   clientId/sessionId: "XXXXXX" //generate when user logged in,
   date:""
  }

  setCredentials(credentials) {
    this.cred = credentials;

    if (credentials) {
      localStorage.setItem(this.credentialsKey, JSON.stringify(credentials));
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem(this.credentialsKey);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `localStorage.setItem('socketSessionId', 'generated-uid');` at the beginning only if `socketSessionId` values doesn't exists in local storage. Also can you post the code where you set `localStorage` values for `sessionId` in client?

Comment: @v1shva. I set it after user logged in

on refresh there is a token exists so I take the object from the storage 

so a new socket will be created with the same client id 
its ok for tabs but its not ok for refresh

Comment: I think issue is that when refreshed user is logged in again and a new clientId is generated, even though it's the same tab, so either you have to check the localStorage before logging in or, at the backend group connections by user instead of session. so each user can have multiple connections, so when refreshed, previous socketio connection can be removed by removing them on `disconnect` event. Also ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930559/handle-browser-refresh-socket-io

Comment: @v1shva if i have 2 tabs opens 
and in one of the tab i refresh the page , now i will have 3 socket 
how can I remove the old one 

I can find his socket by the id the I generated ? so I dont need to use the same id from local storage ?

another question , can I catch disconnected on refresh ?